# Mobile safari - ios version 6.0.1 (10A523) - incorrect checkbox id

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I am having an unusual problem with mobile safari on the iPad. I am using the following code to get the id of a checkbox when it is clicked, but the id value I am getting is not correct all times.

html code:

```
  <input name="CheckBoxes" id="id1" data-theme="d" type="checkbox"  class="use-reports-checkbox">
  <label for="id1">Select</label>
  <input name="CheckBoxes" id="id2" data-theme="d" type="checkbox"  class="use-reports-checkbox">
  <label for="id2">Select</label>
  <input name="CheckBoxes" id="id3" data-theme="d" type="checkbox"  class="use-reports-checkbox">
  <label for="id3">Select</label>
```

And then I'm using this jquery code to get the id value:

```
    $(".use-reports-checkbox").on("change", function () {
      var selectedId = $(this).attr("id");
      alert("selectedId: " + selectedId); //this.id does the same thing
    }
```

It works in the desktop browsers, but on mobile safari, it's bizarre. If I try to check the first two checkboxes, the alert gives me id1 both times, and it's checking and unchecking the first checkbox only. 
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Debarupa/y7B8n/5/

Comment: For debugging, it's better not to use alert. Use console.log or any other method. I've tested code with some changes on iPad 2 v7 it works with no issues whatsoever http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/pFphD/1/show/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see that it works when inside pageinit. I tried to use pageinit before (with mvc4), but ran into problems I don't remember now. So I started using $(document).ready and never changed that. Guess I'll have to try to use pageinit again to see if I still get issues.

Comment: For JQM use page events rather than using .ready() and don't use alert to debug. Good luck :)